# Split text with javascript without losing data

Tags: javascript

I have a code for splitting text but it is losing some data. My question is how to split a text and keep all data. My code below?

```
 function splitArray(){
    var myStr = "| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here | 07.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you | 07.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites | 07.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need";
    var strArray = myStr.split(" | 0");

    // Display array values on page
    for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        $("body").append("<p>" + strArray[i] + "</p>");
    }
}
```

the problem is here it removes the number (0) before date 7

| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here

7.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you

7.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites

7.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need

Comment: Split on `|` and reduce..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `RegExp` with `positive lookahead`.

Few people asked **what if** the number doesn't start with `0` - then you should use `/(?= \| \d)/`. In case, that you care only about numbers starting with `0` - use `/(?= \| 0)/`

```js
function splitArray(){
    var myStr = "| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here | 17.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you | 07.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites | 07.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need";
    var strArray = myStr.split(/(?= \| \d)/);

    // Display array values on page
    for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        $("body").append("<p>" + strArray[i] + "</p>");
    }
}
splitArray();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if the date does not start with a `0`?

Comment: @Mistalis I don't think OP had the requirement to look up for anything other than `0`

Comment: @Mistalis It's fixed.

Comment: @Fran There was another solution, but it's owner already deleted his post, that's why I've used `either` word (:

Comment: @Kinduser What if OP intentionally wanted to ignore numbers other than `0`? - My point,....over-coding beyond specified requirement can lead to undesired results. Even if in this case it might be fitting.

Comment: @Kinduser I've deleted it, because yours was highly better... ;P

Comment: @Fran You can guess as an evidence it is a chat with dates... I'm pretty sure he needs it to work for every date, not only dates starting with 0.

Comment: @Mistalis Never guess, always confirm with the person giving the requirements, bad habit to get into, even if it seems obvious, as some clients have the strangest requirements. Unless you work with a client so long that you can foresee their desires it's never a good idea to guess. imho -

Comment: @Fran Agreed, it's better to return exactly what OP was asking for. But it's also fine to let him know about other, helpful features.

Comment: Thanks Kind user, this code works. Just as l asked :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way without using regex. It works, but I think [*@Kind user's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650063/4927984) is better.

```js
var myStr = "| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here | 07.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you | 07.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites | 07.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need";
    var strArray = myStr.split("|");

    // Display array values on page
    for (var i = 1; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        $("body").append("<p>" + strArray[i] + " | " + strArray[i + 1] + "</p>");
        i++;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP knows that and wants to split the string at those exact positions but wants to retain the `0` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can split on `|` and then transform it to a better format;

```
var myStr = "| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here | 07.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you | 07.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites | 07.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need";
var strArray = myStr.split("|");

var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < strArray.length; i += 2) {
    result.push(strArray[i] + ' | ' + strArray[i + 1]);
}

//= results should be a array with the entries
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
var strArray = myStr.split(" | ?<=0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does, as it is part of the separator. Furthermore this would not work if your date does not start with a 0. So try splitting these up in pairs.

**Untested:**

```
function splitArray(){
  var myStr = "| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here | 07.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you | 07.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites | 07.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need";
  var strArray = myStr.split('|');
  // remove the first empty element
  strArray.splice(0, 1);

  if (strArray.length % 2 !== 0)
    console.log('Parsing error');

  var messageArray = [];

  while(strArray.length > 0) {
    var pair = strArray.splice(0, 2);
    messageArray.push(pair.join('|'));
  }

  // Display array values on page
  for (var i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++) {
    $("body").append("<p>" + messageArray[i] + "</p>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression with a positive look ahead and split if pipe, space and a number is found.

```js
var myStr = "| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here | 07.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you | 07.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites | 07.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need";
    var strArray = myStr.split(/(?=\|\s+\d+)/);

console.log(strArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just append a zero with before appending like this:

```
 function splitArray(){
    var myStr = "| 07.02.2017 13:49:25 | Guest 6278: Hi anybody here | 07.02.2017 13:49:58 | Admin: Yes, how may l help you | 07.02.2017 13:50:25 | Guest 6278: Do we have to change sites | 07.02.2017 13:50:58 | Admin: No, no need";
    var strArray = myStr.split(" | 0");

    // Display array values on page
    for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    if(i==0)
        $("body").append("<p>" + strArray[i] + "</p>");
        else $("body").append("<p>" +0+ strArray[i] + "</p>");
    }
}
splitArray();
```